# Jenkins: multijob phase - manipulate predefined parameters

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Lets say I have a parameterized multijob and I want to pass a parameter to a downstream job

[image]

but i want to manipulate it like add chars or upcase.

[image]

so the passed parameter to 'feed animal' job would be 'MAMAL-dog' eventually. how is it possible?